# jQuery if there is no url in img tag then img tag should be deleted

Tags: jquery, image

Is it possible to check with jQuery if in an image tag an image url is inside and if there is not that the img tag will not show?

HTML now:

```
<div id="slide">
    <img src="http://www.url.com/.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.url.com/.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" /> - here is no img url so this one must be deleted
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target images with an empty source, and remove them :

```
$('#slide img[src=""]').remove();
```

or the `filter()` method :

```
$('#slide img').filter(function() {
    return ! $.trim( this.getAttribute('src') ).length;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("img").each(function(){
     if($(this).attr("src") == "") {
           $(this).remove();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works:

```
$('#slide').find('img[src=""]').remove();
```